How to calculate ionic charge density in Quantum Espresso?
I am trying to calculate total charge density of surface slab along z axis. I am using from QUantum Espresso. I know that using plot_num=0, I can calculate the electronic charge density in pp.x. Now, I need to find ionic charge density to calculate total charge density. I couldn't find any option in Quantum Espresso to calculate ionic charge density along z axis.
